# chained AND condition gives ambiguous result

Tags: python

Can someone explain the following?

```
a = [2,3,4]
b = [5,6,8,9]

print(len(a) > 0)
print(len(b) > 0)
print((len(a) > 0) & len(b) > 0))
```

Output:

```
True
True
False
```

Shouldn't the last print statement return True? If I now rewrite it as:

```
print((len(a) > 0) & (len(b) > 0))
```

(notice the brackets around the second AND condition), I get the output as `True`.

This is baffling to me. Why does including the second AND condition in brackets change the result?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`&` is not the logical "and" operator. It's the bitwise "and" operator, and as such, it has precedence suitable for a bitwise operation rather than a logical one. That precedence is higher than the precedence for comparison, so the expression is parsed as

```
((len(a) > 0) & len(b)) > 0
```

If you use a logical `and`, the precedence works the way you expect:

```
print(len(a) > 0 and len(b) > 0)
```

Comment: Thanks for making me feel so stupid.

But seriously, thanks! Can't believe I didn't think of this.