# Bitwise operator & in Python

Tags: python, conditional-statements, bitwise-operators

Recently I was solving one of the very basic problems on conditionals from Hackerrank.

The problem was:

> If n is odd, print Weird 
>   If n is even and in the inclusive range of 2 to 5 print Not Weird 
>   If n is even and in the inclusive range of 6 to 20 print Weird 
>   If n is even and greater than 20, print Not Weird

So i wrote the following code

```
if(n % 2 == 0 & n >=6 & n <= 20 ):
    print("Weird")
elif(n % 2 == 0 & n <= 2 & n >= 5): 
     print("Not Weird")
elif( n % 2 != 0):
     print("Weird")
else:
     print("Not Weird")
```

It didn't work at first. I figured out that i had to use "and" instead of "&". 
But, I am not convinced why did this happen.. 
for n = 12, all 3 conditions of the first if condition are true. so true & true & true should also be true, right?

[this photo shows the code snippet with some print messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESdX4.png)

I am very intrigued to know the reason behind this behaviour, please guide! (may be something very minor but please don't mind :) )

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Logical vs bitwise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8418295/logical-vs-bitwise)

Comment: it returns True if you do (n % 2 == 0) & (n >=6) & (n <= 20), so it is probably related to the order in which the elements are evaluated in the if-statement

Comment: Does this answer your question? [chained AND condition gives ambiguous result](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37401219/354577)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [chained AND condition gives ambiguous result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37401219/chained-and-condition-gives-ambiguous-result)

Comment: The second dupe I suggested is probably better. `&` and `and` have different precedence.

Comment: yes it was about the precedence ! thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you have this kind of doubts, you can use the `dis` module, in your case I make a lambda function to evaluate the process:

```py
func = lambda x: x % 2 == 0 & x >= 6 & x <= 20
```

this gives us the follow disassmbled code:

```
              0 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 (2)
              4 BINARY_MODULO
              6 LOAD_CONST               2 (0)
              8 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
             10 BINARY_AND
             12 DUP_TOP
             14 ROT_THREE
             16 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             18 JUMP_IF_FALSE_OR_POP    40
             20 LOAD_CONST               3 (6)
             22 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
             24 BINARY_AND
             26 DUP_TOP
             28 ROT_THREE
             30 COMPARE_OP               5 (>=)
             32 JUMP_IF_FALSE_OR_POP    40
             34 LOAD_CONST               4 (20)
             36 COMPARE_OP               1 (<=)
             38 RETURN_VALUE
        >>   40 ROT_TWO
             42 POP_TOP
             44 RETURN_VALUE
```

explained is just:

- Get var `x` value
- Get const `2` value
- Get `modulo` comparison between `2` and `x`, the answer is `0` when you use `12` as the param value.
- Get const `0` value
- Get var `x` value
- Get Binary `and` comparison between `0` and `x`, naturally, a bitwise operation between any value (eg: `b'1100'`) and `b'0000'` will return `0`.
- Next, values are stored in TOP and compared with `==` operator. This means as other answers said `(x % 2) == (0 & x)` at this time, with `x` being `12`, the translated operation is `0 == 0` (True).
- With the `==` result check if is False (in that case, jump to row `40` of bytecode) else, remove the result (POP) from TOS (Top of stack)
- Get const `6` value
- Get var `x` value
- Another `and` comparison, this time between `6` (`b'0110'`) and `12` (`x` = `b'1100'`) with a result of `4` (`b'0100'`)
- The last result is stored in TOP and compared with `>=` operator with the last stored value (`0 >= 4` as said in other answers).
- Response from `0 >= 4` is then, evaluated in the next instruction, `False` causes than the code skip directly to the instruction `40` (Return False) without even test the last case.

Of course, this is the bytecode explanation of how python works, the short answer is the `0 & n >= 6 & n` thing, with this in mind, we can assume than every number different from 0, will return False to this evaluation, because a bitwise operation between `b'0110'` will always be greater than 0.

### TL;DR

Bitwise operators are evaluated before Boolean operators.

### References

https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/dis.html Dis module reference.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, this will be useful for clearing any  other doubts in future!!

Answer (score 0):

> for n = 12, all 3 conditions of the first if condition are true.

```
>>> n = 12
>>> n % 2 == 0 & n >= 6 & n <= 20
False
```

The second condition is false (and the conditions aren't what you think they are, because bitwise operators are similar to other numeric operators [`+`, `-`, `%`, etc] in that they have higher precedence than comparison operators).

Let's break this down a little:

```
>>> n % 2
0
>>> 0 & n
0
>>> 6 & n
4
>>> 0 == 0 >= 4 <= 20
False
```

The expression is false because of the `0 & n >= 6 & n` condition.  0 isn't greater than 4!

Comment: oh i see that's what happened! thanks for breaking it down so clearly!

Answer (score 0):

It may not be immediately obvious from the [grammar](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations), but binary arithmetic operations bind tighter than binary bitwise operations. So your comparison is the same as

```
>>> if(n % 2 == (0 & n) >= (6 & n) <= 20 ):
...     print("Weird")
... 
>>>
```

Your "true & true &true" case is

```
>>> if((n % 2 == 0) & (n >=6) & (n <= 20) ):
...     print('Weird')
... 
Weird
```

But that only works because python `True` and `False` evaluate to `1` and `0`. A bitwise operation only works because of this underlying representation.